# How to overwrite old dataframe on each iteration?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I implement a for-loop in Spark where I overwrite the old/original dataframe on each iteration? Something like this:

```
val columns = Seq("a","b")
val data = Seq((1, 102),
    (2, 103),
    (3, 104)
)
val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)

for( iteration <- 1 to 3) yield{

    val temp = df.filter($"b" >= 100).withColumn("b", exampleUDF(lit(iteration), $"b"))

    //
    // other computation stuff
    //

    df = temp
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use a `var` df?

```
val columns = Seq("a","b")
val data = Seq((1, 102),
    (2, 103),
    (3, 104)
)
var df = data.toDF(columns:_*)

for(iteration <- 1 to 3) {
    df = df.filter($"b" >= 100).withColumn("b", exampleUDF(lit(iteration), $"b"))
}
```

Comment: Or a simple tail recursive algorithm to avoid mutability.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `foldLeft` method for that:

```
val finalDF = (1 to 3).foldLeft(df){(acc, iter) => 
     acc.filter($"b" >= 100)
        .withColumn("b", exampleUDF(lit(iter), $"b"))
}
```